# get url from textarea - JQUERY

Tags: jquery

I try to get url from a textarea but nothing is happening.
What is wrong?

```
<textarea name="comment" id="comment" class="comment" placeholder=""></textarea>

function isUrl(s) {
    var regexp = /(ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/
    return regexp.test(s);
}

$('#comment').keyup(function() {
    if(isUrl($(this).val()){
       alert($(this).val());
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uayp13fd/

Comment: You had a typo - you've missed one parenthesis in this line: `if(isUrl($(this).val()){`. It should be `if(isUrl($(this).val())){`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to

```
function isUrl(s) {
    var regexp = /(ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/;
    return regexp.test(s);
}

$('#comment').keyup(function() {
    if(isUrl($(this).val())){
       alert($(this).val());
    }
});
```

Comment: You are welcome) You can mark answer so other people can see your question as resolved:)

Answer (score 1):

You have indeed missed one parenthesis ")".
This is why I prefer putting strings in variables to minimize the chance of mistakes -and to troubleshoot easier:

```
function isUrl(s) {
    var regexp = /(ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/
    return regexp.test(s);
}


$('#comment').keyup(function() {
    var thisVal = $(this).val();
    if(isUrl(thisVal)){
       alert(thisVal);
    }
});
```